# Why is my time range query slow even when I have BRIN index on the timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table that stores chat messages, like so;

id (int8), timestamp (timestamp), author (text), channel(text), content(text)

I have BTREE indexes on all of the fields, except for timestamp, which is a BRIN index. My query is:

```
explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, costs)
select * from chat_messages where "timestamp" between '2022-05-17 13:30:00' AND '2022-05-17 13:32:00'
```

Here is the output:

```
Buffers: shared hit=6 read=2
Gather  (cost=1014.34..47496.04 rows=178 width=65) (actual time=31636.165..48582.533 rows=509 loops=1)
"  Output: id, ""timestamp"", channel, author, content"
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=142 read=20743 dirtied=238 written=17
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.chat_messages  (cost=14.34..46478.24 rows=74 width=65) (actual time=31407.597..48451.121 rows=170 loops=3)
"        Output: id, ""timestamp"", channel, author, content"
"        Recheck Cond: ((chat_messages.""timestamp"" >= '2022-05-17 13:30:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (chat_messages.""timestamp"" <= '2022-05-17 13:32:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 579089
        Heap Blocks: lossy=6948
        Buffers: shared hit=142 read=20743 dirtied=238 written=17
        Worker 0:  actual time=31103.912..48405.671 rows=188 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=64 read=6895 dirtied=95 written=4
        Worker 1:  actual time=31493.725..48405.985 rows=151 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=66 read=6904 dirtied=102 written=6
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ts_index  (cost=0.00..14.29 rows=765117 width=0) (actual time=30.846..30.851 rows=208770 loops=1)
"              Index Cond: ((chat_messages.""timestamp"" >= '2022-05-17 13:30:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (chat_messages.""timestamp"" <= '2022-05-17 13:32:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=98 read=17
Planning Time: 205.476 ms
Execution Time: 48583.437 ms
```

I don't understand why it has to fetch so many rows, my Database is on a Hard drive and I believe that exacerbates the issue, but I thought the point of a BRIN index was so that it can be segmented by time, so it wouldn't have to perform so many disk reads.

Is there something wrong with my BRIN index?

Comment: BRIN indexes are good when your data has natural correlation by the index key https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin-intro.html looking at the number of rows it thinks it needs to search after the index, your data isn't that well suited (there may be some index parameters to make it better but I'm not aware of the internals). You would be better off with a standard B-Tree index. BTW an index on each column is usually a sign of guesswork, you're only going to use one to read the data here, make sure the others have uses.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I added the other indexes because I want to search messages by all of those fields. The page you linked says that "most of the time the entries for earlier orders will appear earlier in the table as well", that is true for my table, is it not?

Comment: We can't see the physical distribution of data within your table, it would make sense if things were serially insert to with a current timestamp. However, the number of rows identified by the index suggests there's a lot of blocks which have ranges of data which would include your filter.

Comment: The docs suggest you might need to run the summarize call for newer data, which will automatically happen when you `vacuum`. Is this something you can schedule?

Comment: I ran a full vacuum on the table (2.7 million rows), but the query took the exact same amount of time afterwards

Comment: I would go with the classic B-Tree index instead then, no need to worry about the lossy nature of BRIN indexes. A B-Tree will give you predictable, decent performance

Comment: You could try to [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-cluster.html) by your `TIMESTAMP`?